# Anylogic: System dynamics and randomness (triangular or normal) in flows gives wrong results

Tags: anylogic, stock

I am trying to create a dynamic environment in anylogic with portfolio performance over the time.
The return each year should be dynamic (random) using triangular or normal
Example triangular (-0.5,0.1,0.5) or normal(0.05,0.08)
That means sometimes it is positive and sometimes it's negative

Dynamic variable/parameter is 'Return1'
Flow is 'earn'
Stock is 'portfolio'

I use a variable Return1 = normal(0.05,0.08)
A Flow earn = portfolio*Return1
The stock is called Portfolio and initial value of 100. It accumulates the profit/loss each year
Unfortunately the results  in the accumulated portfolio are not correct.

If I use Return1=0.1 or for example -0.05 (fixed prices) it works perfectly.

It seems there are issues in anylogic system dynamics with randomness.
I would appreciate if you can help how I could simulate the portfolio performance in this way

Comment: Thanks. I simulate it using 1 second per step. So , there is no any trusted way to create the randomness for that case? The event will pass the value to Return1 after each step and them the flow will is it correctly now? If not, could I use an excel file where I can have the random values there and pass them to the variable in each step? For example in excel file Params.excel, I have a tab return 1 where I have a list of values that will be used in each step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you want, you need to recalculate the random variable in your variable every year. Maybe create an event that runs once per year that changes the value of the variable.

In the event you would have every year:

```
Return1 = normal(0.05,0.08)
```

The variable Return1 is not magically updated automatically based on your own desires and wishes, unless you tell Anylogic explicitely.

If return1 is a dynamic variable, then the value will be recalculated every time step, which will lead to unexpected results that will be maybe equivalent to using the average of your random value.

If your time step is 1 year... well in AnyLogic you can't really trust that time step unfortunately.

Comment: I did it with recurrence every one second, since the simulation unit was 1 sec. What it shows is that the same value remains the same for 2 steps. Return1 = Return1*(1+ triangular(-0.3,0.1,0.3)); where Return1 is a parameter with initial value 100. Then the result is like 100, 96.604,96.604,116.715, 116,715,95.849, 95849 etc. Is it something wrong with the time and show duplications?